# How to use Dense Rank for Date Field in BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to filter for only latest 4 weeks of data in BusinessObjects. In the below example I want to retrieve data for below dates (latest weeks). `Week Date` is a field which is every Monday date of the week.

1. `10/9/2017`
2. `10/2/2017`
3. `9/25/2017`
4. `9/18/2017`

```
Week Date   Sales
8/28/2017   100
8/28/2017   101
9/4/2017    102
9/4/2017    103
9/11/2017   104
9/11/2017   105
9/18/2017   106
9/18/2017   107
9/25/2017   108
9/25/2017   109
10/2/2017   110
10/2/2017   111
10/9/2017   112
```

I tried with Rank Function and spent hours finding solution but had no luck. I hope Dense Rank would help, later I can filter for 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one variable and a filter on that variable, but I like to break things down to understand exactly what is happening. You can always combine variables later.

First, create a variable to represent the cutoff date...

```
[CutOff Date] = RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -4; WeekPeriod)
```

Second, create another variable to determine if a particular week should be included...

```
[Last Four Weeks] = If([Week Date] > [CutOff Date]; 1; 0)
```

Finally, create filter on to only show the last four weeks...

```
[Last Four Weeks] = 1
```

You may need to adjust the values depending on the timing of when you are running your report, but that is the general idea.

As I mentioned earlier, you could combine [CutOff Date] and [Last Four Weeks] into one variable...

```
[Last Four Weeks] = If([Week Date] > RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -4; WeekPeriod)
; 1; 0)
```

Noel

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used the same but in other way `[DateFilter] = IF(Max[Week Date] >= RelativeDate(CurrentDate();-27;"Yes";"No")`